# What is the better way to merge the excel cells in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to merge certain cells of a row in vb.net. When I use

```vb
xlApp.Range("A9:A11").Select()
xlApp.Range("A9:A11").Merge()
```

it works perfectly.

But when I try to do

```vb
xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(Rownumber, StartColumn), 
                  xlWorkSheet.Cells(Rownumber, EndColumn)).Merge()
```

getting an error as

Error Message:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
>
> Stack Trace
>
> at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int320] aWrapperTypes. MessageData& msgData) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.Merge(Object Across)
>
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

I tried

```vb
xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(Rownumber, StartColumn), 
                  xlWorkSheet.Cells(Rownumber, EndColumn)).Select()
```

before merging. Still no luck.

Can anybody tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: What are the values of `Rownumber`, `StartColumn`, and `EndColumn` when this fails?

Comment: @BigBen They are some dynamic integer values and vary based on some conditions. For example, something like `Rownumber=16, StartCol=3 and Endcolumn=9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason was not how the Merging was done. For some weird reason, some groups of cells in the Excel were marked as a table. So, the merging the cells is not allowed for the table cells. Due to this, the code was throwing an exception.
Once I changed the cells of my Excel template file to type 'range' **(Table design -> Convert to Range)**

, the below code worked,

```
xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(Rownumber, StartColumn), 
                  xlWorkSheet.Cells(Rownumber, EndColumn)).Merge()
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is set a range, then merge.  The range must be **valid**.  The merge CAN cause loss of data.

```
    ' XLSheet is a worksheet object
    ' XLRange is a range object
    '
    XLRange = XLSheet.Range(Cell1:=XLSheet.Cells(sRW + 1, sCOL + 1),
                            Cell2:=XLSheet.Cells(maxRW, maxCOL))
    XLRange.Merge()
```

Comment: I am also doing the same but in one line. I don't think it makes any difference to the logic. Anyway, I tried separating setting a range, then merging, like you suggested. It did not make any difference.